# How To Get A checkbox Value On Checked In Reactjs And Concatenate It With API

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm working on a checkbox filter in Reactjs application with backend Laravel I need to get a checkbox value on a check and add that value in API URL and then fetch data on the checkbox checked.

**frontend Api**

```
export const getFilteredPets = (Male, Female) => {
const data = {
    Male, Female
}
return fetch(`${API}/pet/by/search?qp_pet_gender`, {
    method:"POST",
    headers:{
        Accept: 'application/json',
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(response =>{
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
});
};
```

**checkbox.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect}  from 'react';
const Checkbox = ({genders, handelFilters}) => {
const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);

const handelToggle = g => () => {
    const currentPetId = checked.indexOf(g)
    const newCheckedPetId = [...checked];
    if(currentPetId === -1){
        newCheckedPetId.push(g)
    }else{
        newCheckedPetId.splice(currentPetId, 1)
    }
    //console.log(newCheckedPetId);
    setChecked(newCheckedPetId)
    handelFilters(newCheckedPetId);
}



return genders.map((g, i) =>(
    
    <li key={i} className="list-unstyled">
    <input onChange={handelToggle(g.name)} value={checked.indexOf(g.name === -1)} type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" />
    <label className="form-check-label">{g.name}</label>
</li>
      
));
}
export default Checkbox;
```

**listing.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Card from "./Card";
import WhySafari from "./WhySafari";  
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";
import Instagram from "./Instagram";
import Testimonial from "./Testimonial";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import {genders} from "./Genders";
import {getPuppies, getFilteredPets} from "./apiCore";


const Listing = () => {

const [myFilters, setMyFilters] = useState({
    filters: { gender: [] }
});

const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [male, setLimit] = useState('Male');
const [female, setSkip] = useState('Female');
const [size, setSize] = useState(0);
const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState([]);

const loadFilteredResults = newFilters => {
    //console.log(newFilters);
    getFilteredPets(male, female, newFilters).then(data => {
        if(data.error){
            setError(data.error);
        }else{
            setFilteredResults(data);
        }
    });

};

const handelFilters = (filters, filterBy) => {
    console.log("Pet Gender", filters, filterBy);
    const newFilters = {...myFilters};
    newFilters.filters[filterBy] = filters;
    setMyFilters(newFilters);
    loadFilteredResults(myFilters.filters);
};


return(
    <div>  
        <Menu/>
        <div className="bradcam_area breadcam_bg">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                        <div className="bradcam_text text-center">
                            <h3>Puppies For Sale</h3>
                            <p>At Safari Stan’s you can rest assured that your new puppy is coming from a vetted,
                                responsible breeder. We are a community of dog lovers committed to helping you find the
                                perfect puppy for your experience level, family and home.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section className="sample-text-area">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-3"></div>
            <div className="col-lg-9 col-12">
                <div className="listing-top-bar">
                    <div className="left-toggle"><i className="ti ti-filter"></i> Filter</div>
                    <div className="search-result">Showing 119 puppies out of 300 Puppies</div>
                    <div className="short-by">

                        <select className="cs-select cs-skin-elastic">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Short By</option>
                            <option>Featured</option>
                            <option>Color</option>
                            <option>Name</option>
                            <option>Young to Old</option>
                            <option>Old to Young</option>
                            <option>Price Low to high</option>
                            <option>Price High to Low</option>
                          </select>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-3">
                <div className="left-panel">
                    <div className="close-menu"><i className="ti ti-close"></i></div>
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-main-header">
                                <h3 className="mt-0">Browser By:</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-header" role="tab" id="accordionHeadingOne">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionBodyOne"
                                    aria-expanded="ture" aria-controls="accordionBodyOne" className=" ">
                                    Gender
                                    <i className="ti ti-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div id="accordionBodyOne" className="card-body pl-0 collapse show" role="tabpanel"
                                aria-labelledby="accordionHeadingOne" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="accordion">

                                <ul className="unstyled centered">
                                <Checkbox genders={genders} 
                                        handelFilters={filters =>
                                        handelFilters(filters, 'gender')}/>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
                <div className="row">
                    {JSON.stringify(filteredResults)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
    </div>
   );
   };
   export default Listing;
```

I want when a check on checkbox my URL will b like **${API}/pet/by/search?qp_pet_gender=Male** or **${API}/pet/by/search?qp_pet_gender=Female**. I'm getting a checkbox value on checked Male, Female in console. Plase help me or guide me

[image]

Comment: You just need to add the variable in your string. `return fetch(`${API}/pet/by/search?qp_pet_gender=${Male || Female}`

Comment: @NisanthReddy sir thanks for your replay but it not filtered the data and in console it gives me this  URL http://localhost/safaripet/backend/public/api/pet/by/search?qp_pet_gender=6 why???

Comment: Post your full code. Where are you using the `getFilteredPets` function ?

Comment: yes I post my code..now please check

Comment: What is `skip, limit, newFilters` ? How should be included into your api ?

Comment: I update my code please check again. Now this gives me only male gender data on both male-female checks. I upload a screenshot, please check.